# Query to find intervals

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I've a table in my DB that has some values like

```
+------+-------+                                                                                                                     
| ID   | VALUE |                                                                                                                     
+------+-------+                                                                                                                     
|    1 | 0001  |                                                                                                                     
|    2 | 0003  |                                                                                                                     
|    3 | 0004  |                                                                                                                     
|    4 | 0005  |                                                                                                                     
|    5 | 0008  |                                                                                                                     
|    6 | 0009  |                                                                                                                     
+------+-------+
```

I need a query that returns the interval of column VALUE, example

```
+-------------+                                                                                                                     
|    VALUE    |                                                                                                                     
+-------------+                                                                                                                     
|  0001       |                                                                                                                     
|  0003-0005  |                                                                                                                     
|  0008-0009  |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
+------+------+
```

How can I do this without using some other procedural languages ? 
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Think about how you can use either a self-join or a WHERE EXISTS() clause to solve the issue.   If you get any errors, please post your attempt and the error you got.

Answer (score 0):

Doing that programmatically in Java (or whatever), the logic can be

1. Fetch the rows from the DB, order by increasing `VALUES`
2. Starting from the second row, for each rows,

   - For each value between ]previous row value, current row value[

     - insert a new row with the missing value and a new ID